# Solomon and Nebuchadnezzar

Tags: midrash, melachim-kings-book-of, arizal, king-solomon

In [1 Kings 10:13](https://chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/15894/showrashi/true/jewish/Chapter-10.htm#v13), Rashi says there that:

> He cohabited with her and Nebuchadnezzar was born to her. He later destroyed the Temple that had stood 410 years in the territory of the twelve tribes. ***From the Arizal***.

**Does this mean Solomon was the father of Nebuchadnezzar, or that Nebuchadnezzar came from Solomon?**

Can someone provide the source where the Arizal said this or hinted to this.

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out how Rashi said that quoting someone who was alive 400+ years after Rashi died.

Comment: "("Alphabet Ben Sira," ed. Venice, 21b; comp. Brüll's "Jahrb." ix. 9)" https://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/11407-nebuchadnezzar  and the story seems to be here https://coproduced-religions.org/resources/case-studies/his-mother-the-queen-of-sheba-a-case-of-religious-co-production and this site mentions an unsourced "midrash" https://aish.com/king-solomon-and-the-queen-of-sheba/

Comment: There's a reason it's in parentheses ... surprised Chabad chose to include it. It's not Rashi. The proper translation is "was born *from* her", not "*to* her." Which would reasonably imply some distant descendant many generations.

Comment: @rosends wow my mistake I really didn't think of that and always assumed Chabad included Rashi

Comment: @Shalom I see now, I did not catch that. Thank you

Comment: @rosends Thank you for the sources!

Comment: I've seen this discussed recently and found a list of more sources, but without exact citations: the Shalah Hakadosh in Parshas Mattos, sefer Kol Bochum by R’ Moshe Galanti in his commentary on Eicha, and Seder Hadoros

Comment: @Shalom I think Chabad included it because everyone does. It's in many Nachs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw this related in the sefer Shalsheles Hakabbalah written by [Gedaliah ibn Yahya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gedaliah_ibn_Yahya_ben_Joseph).

He writes [there](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=6618&st=&pgnum=240&hilite=) (starts on the bottom line):

> אומר המדרש שזאת המלכה נתעברה משלמה ועשתה בת וממנה נולד נבוכדנצר שחרב הבית
>
> This Midrash says that the Queen (of Sheba) cohabited with Shlomo and she bore a daughter, and from her (the daughter) Nevuchadnezzar was born and he destroyed the Temple.

Comment: Note, this doesn't answer the question of "where does the Arizal say this"?

Comment: @Rabbi_Kaii - The OP is only making an assumption and doesn't give any more details...

Comment: It is printed in many Nachs, in brackets in Rashi: https://www.sefaria.org/Rashi_on_I_Kings.10.13.2?vhe=The_Metsudah_Tanach_series,_Lakewood,_N.J_&lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he, also see the OP's source

Comment: Anyway, do you think the same question can be asked on the above? Was Nevuchadnezzar Shlomo's grandson, or does it just mean he is a descendant of his daughter